# How could I automatically update and display a variable in a view, in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, comet

I have a number of users.

Each user has a number of bets, made by and against him.

The total number of bets "belonging" to a user is: `bets_won + bets_lost + bets_in_progress`.

On each user's profile, the user can set whether or not he had won or lost a bet by clicking a radio button for each bet (won, lost or in progress).

Now, I'd like to display the user's "Winning Percentage" (`bets_won / (bets_won + bets_lost) * 100%`) on the profile page in real-time; that is, when the user sets a bet to "won" status, his "Winning Percentage" should automatically be updated on his profile without having to refresh the page.

How could this be done?

Comment: guess that juggernaut gem will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. AJAX polling
2. WEB Sockets (look at [SocketIO](http://socket.io/))
3. Or complete COMET like [juggernaut](https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut) (or [old version](http://juggernaut.rubyforge.org/))

For small feature I preffer to use AJAX polling. For big complicated things I use juggernaut. I've never used SocketIO but it looks very sexy